# Laravel - Integrating paypal for each user

Tags: laravel, paypal

How am I able to make paypal payment method for each user? I made an application where all users are selling their packages and I want to make paying with PP for each of them?

I searched for some tutorials but it is only for ecommerce like one email and one API.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a standard PayPal Checkout integration, but with an additional  `payee` object specified in the order's `purchase_units`:

```
  purchase_units: [{
    amount: {
      currency_code: 'USD',
      value: '220.00'
    },
    payee: {
      email_address: 'USERRECEIVINGPAYMENT@EXAMPLE.COM'
    }
  }]
```

See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/

---

As for how to do a standard PayPal Checkout integration, the most robust solution is to implement two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

And to use this for the customer's approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server